# How can I link multiple binaries files in Qt?

Tags: qt

I need to use a huge library for svg rendering in Qt. My problem is that I used Dependency Walker to find all the dependencies but I am unable to find a way to compile all this files in Qt and make a static library with them and further use it in my project.

This are the files that I manage to find and I need to use: [librSvg binaries](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ed03dfd0f92065a39d19038cfbc35e4d20180612062324/c7ed2a)

Can somebody please explain to me how this should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create static binary you need to link all dependent libraries statically and they should be also compiled statically.

For example:
You want to create static ***example.exe*** with no dynamic dependency.

- ***example.exe*** <- should link ***librsvg*** statically
- depends on ***librsvg*** <- should be compiled *statically*

  - ***librsvg*** depends on ***libpng*, *libsoap*, *etc***... <- to compile ***librsvg*** statically *this* libraries should be also compiled *statically*.

if you have your ***librsvg.a*** with all code compiled statically in it, just instruct compiler to link exactly to this lib by adding:

```
-l/home/user/mylib/release/librsvg.a
```

or in Qt  .pro file:

```
LIBS += /home/user/mylib/release/librsvg.a
```